# Build errors while using minted package

Tags: minted

When i execute latex source, i get following error.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.42 \newmintinline
[command]{LaTeX}{}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Could you supply us with some example code that replicates your current problem? We call this a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you using minted 2.0? Only the latest version supports inline.

Comment: i have installed `texlive-latex-extra` for minted package... is there any way to know which version i am using? I am using Ubuntu 14.04, if that is helpful.

Comment: @G.Poore Can you make an answer?

Answer (score 2):

`\mintinline`, and thus `\newmintinline`, are only supported in `minted` versions 2.0+. This error could be caused by using earlier versions of `minted` in which these commands do not exist. The latest version may be obtained via the TeX Live package manager or directly from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted).